# LazyInitializationException: загрузка вне сессии

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Я использую Spring Data JPA (Hibernate).

Вопрос простой:

можно ли лениво загрузить объект вне сессии или нужно перезагружать всю сущность?

Comment: Вне сессии не выйдет, получите LazyInitializationException

Answer (score 0):

Вне сессии можно, только сессия должна быть открыта. Если у вас возникает исключение [`LazyInitializationException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html),

> Указывает на попытку доступа к еще не полученным данным вне контекста сессии.  Например, когда доступ к неинициализированному прокси или коллекции осуществляется после закрытия сессии.

то это потому, что сессия уже закрыта при попытке инициализировать ленивые элементы.